# Invalid triangle

Tags: graphics, 3d

What is the fastest way to detect an invalid triangle in a 3D Mesh? As invalid I mean:

- zero area
- three collinear points
- two overlapping points

We currently use this - very slow - approach:

```
    if (Area(p1,p2,p3) < 1e-3)

         Debug.WriteLine("Invalid triangle found!");

    public double Area(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3)
    {

        double[,] m = new double[3, 3];

        m[0, 0] = p1.Y; m[0, 1] = p1.Z; m[0, 2] = 1;
        m[1, 0] = p2.Y; m[1, 1] = p2.Z; m[1, 2] = 1;
        m[2, 0] = p3.Y; m[2, 1] = p3.Z; m[2, 2] = 1;

        double det1 = Matrix.Determinant3(m);

        m[0, 0] = p1.Z; m[0, 1] = p1.X; m[0, 2] = 1;
        m[1, 0] = p2.Z; m[1, 1] = p2.X; m[1, 2] = 1;
        m[2, 0] = p3.Z; m[2, 1] = p3.X; m[2, 2] = 1;

        double det2 = Matrix.Determinant3(m);

        m[0, 0] = p1.X; m[0, 1] = p1.Y; m[0, 2] = 1;
        m[1, 0] = p2.X; m[1, 1] = p2.Y; m[1, 2] = 1;
        m[2, 0] = p3.X; m[2, 1] = p3.Y; m[2, 2] = 1;

        double det3 = Matrix.Determinant3(m);

        return Math.Sqrt(det1 * det1 + det2 * det2 + det3 * det3) / 2;


    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Zero area should result from collinear points or overlapping points (as you mentioned). so why not just check for these 2 conditions? much   cheaper i guess.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to have zero area is if the points are all co-linear.

try something like the following:

```
p1_p2_slope = (p2.y - p1.y) / (p2.x - p1.x);
p2_p3_slope = (p3.y - p2.y) / (p3.x - p2.x);
if(p1_p2_slope == p2_p3_slope) {
 // points are collinear
}

if(p1.x == p2.x && p1.y == p2.y) {
  // p1 and p2 overlap
}
if(p1.x == p3.x && p1.y == p3.y) {
  // p1 and p3 overlap
}
if(p3.x == p2.x && p3.y == p2.y) {
  // p3 and p2 overlap
}
```

Comment: We cannot use all these exact comparisons and the slopes can also be opposite and still denote an invalid triangle. With these additions this code would grow in number of lines and become slower...

Answer (score 0):

I think this does it

```
abs(dot(sub(b,a), cross(sub(c,b)))) < epsilon
```

if you want to just expand it I think it works out to this:

```
abs((b.x - a.x) * (c.y - b.y) + (b.y - a.y) * (b.x - c.x)) < epsilon
```

Comment: `abs(dot(sub(b,a), cross(sub(c,b))))` does not seem correct to me, can you check please?